# Maintaining a valid position using seekg in ifstreams

Tags: c++, ifstream, seekg

I am trying to make my file parsing more robust.  Using an ifstream, how can I ensure `seekg` keeps me in a valid position within the file?

This does not work:

```
while(m_File.good() && m_File.peek() != EOF)
{ ...a seekg operation moves file position past end of file... }
```

I assume the current iterator has been pushed way past the end iterator, so the peek() is never true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way of doing this, short of finding the offset of the end of file and making sure you don't seek beyond it, which causes undefined behaviour - you can of course increase the size of the file by writing.

Comment: What is the best way of finding the length of an ifstream?

Comment: It is a shame there is no cleaner way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an error when you reach a bad position (e.g. it shouldn't happen) you may try to set the [stream exception mask](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/exceptions/), and catch the appropriate exception outside of the while loop. In that case it'd be the "cleanest" solution.

Comment: Seeking beyond the ennd of file is undefined behaviour - there is no exception.

Comment: however when reading there is an exception? I'm looking also at this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099601/ifstream-seekg-beyond-end-does-not-return-eof-in-vs-2008-express